While settingup private repo on Nexus getting this error

[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.genwise.club:genwiseclub-library:0.2.1 (C:\Users\meani\Documents\Java_Repo\genwise-library\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.github.platform-team:aws-maven:6.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-models:jar:1.11.276 (present, but unavailable): Could not transfer artifact com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-models:jar:1.11.276 from/to nexus (https://nexus.agex.club/repository/genwise-library-group/): status code: 500, reason phrase: Server Error (500) -> [Help 2] 
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

is there any better way to resolve this problem ??

Better than what?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
